# I'm trying to create a basic android application on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I am a beginner programmer and I'm trying to create a basic android application on eclipse. what i'm trying to do is set up a home screen with a couple of buttons and when you click on a button it will show information which will be held within a list. Each button will show different information. The problem is i don't know how to display the information this is store within each list. Can someone explain how to to do this or have a tutorial that will explain in detail.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest a start from here.
[First Android Application](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)